# How to calculate the weighted average of 5 choices in a survey sent to multiple people?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I asked 9 people to rank the following steps of a supply chain process (planning, Sourcing, Production, Inventory Management, Logistics)  from "Most Seamless" to "Least Seamless."

Now that their answers are in an excel sheet and I am trying to find the weighted average of their answers.

I read a bit about Ranked Choice voting, but I don't want the output to be "X is the highest voted".

I want the output to be something like Inventory management holds a weight of 76 and product has a weight of 56, etc and then sort them from highest to lowest.

I split the rankings between 100 to 0 and I counted the number of times each step occurs per rank.
Then I multiplied the number of times the step occurs by each rank. Finally, I added the product of each rank and divided by 9

Here is what I did so far:

[image: Work so far]

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this ranking and if there was a function an excel to make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` for this.

The formula to create the frequency table (example in cell H2):

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,$G2)
```

The formula in column N2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(H$1:L$1,H2:L2)/9
```

If you wanted it to be more flexible to n, you could replace the 9 with a count of rows between 2 and the bottom of the data table.

[image]

edit:

More specifically (and possibly more accurately if you want the base to only be those who responded), you can use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(H$1:L$1,H2:L2)/SUM(H2:L2)
```

Comment: According to my tests, this seems to be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is an attempt to distill years of graduate level schooling into a couple of paragraphs. You can google words and phrases to get more information.

Unfortunately, your survey instrument captured ordinal data. You are attempting to convert it to interval/ratio data. This cannot be done without major assumptions. For example you don't really know if subject 1 would have given a ranking of 100 if they were asked a question like "on a scale of 0-100 how would you rank the seamlessness of production". Furthermore, you don't know if the second place ranking would have scored 75 if asked about inventory management in the same format. Perhaps to that person it would have scored it a 95.

Your options are to: 1) redo your survey instrument so that you can gather data  that are in line with your desired analysis (you really shouldn't ask the same people so this may not be an option) or 2) Continue down the path of rank choice voting, or other non-parametric type analysis that is suited for the data (qualitative in nature) that you have gathered.

Beyond this, your sample size is too small to generate any valid statistical test. So your findings should be limited to discussion of rankings.